# Get value from foreign key. MySQL. PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get value of foreign key in my view. But i don't know how to do that. My table structure is like:
requisition:
[image: requisition table]

users:
[image: User Table]

requisition_approval

[image: requisition_approval table]

I got all values from the requisition table with:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM requisition where created_by = '$uid'";
$result = $this->fetch($qry);
return $result;
```

But it will return id in foreign key values. I want to get name of user from users table and approval status from the requisition_approval table. How can i do that?

Comment: Use `join` to fetch data. Or you can do it by using `FUNCTIONS`.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to learn about `JOINS`:

```
SELECT R.*, U.*
FROM requisition R
LEFT JOIN users U ON R.created_by=U.id
WHERE R.created_by = '$uid'";
```

From your example, `requisition_approval` table is not clearly linked. You need a common field

Comment: Relation between requisition and requisition_approval is one to one. Should i also add requisition_id in requisition_approval table?

Comment: Yes, you need a common field , so that you do a JOIN and retrieve data, You would add 
`LEFT JOIN requisition_approval A ON A.id=R.requisition_id`

Comment: **OPINION** 
A one to one relationship in two tables is usually a waste. All the fields should be merged into 1 table. There is no real reason to separate into two table, as far as normalization is concerned, they are one and the same